# Why does the SVN command work in one directory, but not another?

Tags: linux, svn

I used SVN to check out the code of an open source project. When I typed the following command:

```
[user1@smallfox]~/workspace/project1% svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk
```

It worked just fine.

However, when I typed the SVN command in the root directory, it did not work and gave me an error message:

```
[user1@smallfox]~% svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk
zsh: command not found: svn
```

Can you tell me why?

Comment: one for the sysadmin forum but it appears the 'svn' tool is not available in your home folder. what does 'whereis svn' tell you?

Comment: After typing "whereis SVN" under the root directory, the system returns "svn: ". What does that mean?

Comment: how did you install svn? It's saying svn is installed in your home dir. what does 'echo $PATH' show you. And what does 'whereis svn' when its run in the './workspace/project1' dir say?

Comment: A question regarding svn could be on-topic for SO, but it sounds like this one will achieve escape-velocity and head toward the sysadmin site, so I'd recommend moving it over there.

Answer (score 4):

Try from your home directory the following and see if it works

```
/workspace/project1/svn co http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/trunk
```

Your path is messed up. svn is probably not in path and also your path was setup with something like

```
export PATH=.:$PATH
```

and svn is present in /workspace/project1/

Much of the above is guess work, since I would need more details, but I would recommend you to revisit the way you installed SVN.